# how do I reexport all imports from a module in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm migrating a JS codebase to TS. In JS we have some index.js files which reexport all imports from a module:

`export * as users from './users';`

What's the equivalent TS for this?

Comment: That is the equivalent. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## It is possible [since TypeScript 3.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#export--as-ns-syntax)

Here's a summary of **re-export ***:

```typescript
// Re-export *
export * as default from './example1' // as default-import
export * from './example2' // separately
export * as ex3 from './example3' // as a named-object

// usage:
// import ex1, { example2Const, ex3 } from './reexport'
// import * as all from './reexport'
```

And a reminder of **re-export picked**:

```typescript
// Re-export chosen
export { a, b as newB, c as default } from "./example4"; // pick what to export

// usage:
// import c, { a, newB } from './reexport'
// import * as all from './reexport'
```

*Docs:*
· [Re-export all](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#allvalidatorsts)
· [Re-export as named object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export-all-as-x)

Answer (score 7):

I haven't found a way to do this as a single line, but a coworker pointed out this approach can work:

```
import * as users from './users';

export {
  users,
};
```

Comment: Your original code works just fine: `export * as users from "./users"`.

Comment: It didn't at the time, perhaps a bug has been fixed. Thanks for calling out that this works now.

Answer (score 1):

@Patrick Finnigan's anwser is not totally correct.
You will have to use `users.XXX` to access symbols.

Seem there is no easy way to export all symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, how to re-export all named exports (but not a default export) from `One` module in `Second` module is to use `export * from './one'`, please see example:

In `one.ts` we have

```
// Will be re-exported in Two.ts
export interface One {
    one: string;
}

// Will be re-exported in Two.ts
export const abc = 'abc';

const magicNumber = 123;

// Will NOT be re-exported in Two.ts
export default magicNumber;
```

In `two.ts` we have

```
import * as fromOne from './one'

export interface Two {
    two: number;
    one: fromOne.One
}
```

and finally we have index.ts, where we can do

```
import * as fromTwo from './two'

const mNumber = fromTwo.magicNumber; // this will fail, default export is not available

const objectFromOneAndTwo: fromTwo.Two = {
    two: 456,
    one: {
        one: fromTwo.abc
    }
}
```